# Determining indexes in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My `NSMutableArray` is from the `NSCachesDirectory`,I'm recreating/reloading the array in every VIEW. I'm displaying/preview it in `UIScrollView` which can be deleted in VIEW_A. In another `ViewController` VIEW_B, I have another preview of it, for another purpose.

What I needed is when I delete the image in VIEW_A, I will be able to determine in VIEW_B the deleted images or index. Because I'm using their indexes in VIEW_B. How can I be able to do it. I'm thinking of saving it all in `NSUserDefaults` but how.

Delete method:

```
    [button removeFromSuperview];

    [_buttons removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
    [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%u.png", button.tag]];           
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
```

I just want to know/determine that indexes that are deleted from other view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i really understood your problem, but here's my response:

If you need to update some object after something change (like your array). You should use a pattern observer. You can get free one with NSNotificationCenter (in foundation lib), but i discourage it. You can use kvo/kvc but it's not as clean as if you'll do in a pattern observer.

By the way, you should use only one array, and if you need to perform change on it, use a specific controller to do it. (Not from the client side like in your UIViewA/B)

here on wiki how to use it (in java, but the skeleton is the same):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

By the way NSUserDefault should be only used to store user preferences, not some app logic values.

Comment: I just want to know/determine that indexes that are deleted from other view.

Comment: that's not done by magic ;). U can do a dirty  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#> name:<#(NSString *)#> object:<#(id)#>] from client side (ur views) to register to the "event"; Where name is the event name. And then post a  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:<#(NSString *)#> object:<#(id)#>] from server side ; where notification name is the "event" name, and object ur post value. As i said, this is the dirtiest approach but simplest one

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use a delegate method.

In VIEW_B set up a delegate protocol and in the delete method have a call to something like...

```
[self.delegate didDeleteImageAtIndex:button.tag];
```

then in VIEW_A before you push VIEW_B set it up as the delegate.

Then in VIEW_A have the method...

```
- (void)didDeleteImageAtIndex:(int)index
{
    //delete image from VIEW_A's array
}
```

Comment: I just want to know/determine that indexes that are deleted from other view.

Comment: I would still use the same thing.  It is the easiest way of letting the original VC know that something has happened in the second VC.  What you do when it gets told is up to you :-D whether you delete it or just mark it as deleted etc...

Comment: Ah, it is a fairly fundamental part of iOS. You can read more here... http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html or you will find docs on the Apple Docs too.

Comment: Delegate is a one to one relationship. Superman want some objectS to be notified when one value change, or something happen. U really need to learn basic code pattern like strategy or observer. This is what u need to accomplish this

Comment: So im going to connect it to the appDelegate?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing with the info. It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  protocol/delegate is different from the appDelegate.  Read up on it first and then decide :D